# question on availability of supervisor

Tags: grammaticality

I want to show some results to my supervisor. before that I need to check with him if he is free or will be free.does the following sentence is grammatically correct and fluent? 
Would you let me know when you are free to show you some results.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a proofreading service; however, if you identify a specific question of grammar or usage that confuses you, we may be able to help. That is, why do *you* think it may be correct or incorrect, and why? What references have you consulted on your own? Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may be of interest to you, but I would recommend taking the [site tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) for a better understanding of how StackExchange operates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is grammatically correct, but I suggest that you rephrase the question in another way to make it more formal and more polite, seeing as this person is your supervisor.

Instead of

> Would you let me know when you are free to show you some results

You can instead say

> Could you please let me know what time is convenient for you, so that I can show you some results?